# Dirichlet sum involving coprimes to p#

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, dirichlet-series

This exercise seemed straightforward but I have not managed to do the following proof. Let $p\#$ be the product of primes not exceeding p. Let $c(n)$ be the nth coprime to $p\#$ (mod 2,3,...,p). Let $X =\prod_{p_i\leq p}\phi(p_i).$ Of course there are X coprimes for given p, beginning in numerical order with 1.

To show: In the limit as p gets large, the sum $$\sum_{n\leq X}\frac{c(n)}{n}\sim p\#. $$

Some evidence--

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
p & \sum c(n)/n &p\#~~~~& \sum c(n)n^{-1}/p\#  \\
\hline
5 &24.89 &30& 0.829\\
\hline
7 &201.05 &210&0.957 \\
\hline
11&2295.08&2310& 0.9935\\
\hline
13&30008.69 &30030&0.99929 \\
\hline
17& 510480.82&510510&0.999943\\
\hline
\end{array}

Putting $C(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{c(n)}{n}$ we can use Abel summation to put

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{c(n)}{n}= \frac{1}{x}C(x)+\int_1^x\frac{C(t)}{t^2}dt$$

and if $x=X,$ I think it's easy to show the first term on the right is $\frac{p\#}{2}.$ Assuming that's true, is there enough information to argue that the integral has the same value? If not, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\# k = \prod_{p \le k} p = e^{\sum_{p \le k} \log p} = e^{k+o(k)}$ (by the PNT) then

$$\sum_{n \le N, gcd(n,\# k) = 1} 1 = \sum_{d | \# k} \mu(d) \lfloor \frac{N}d \rfloor = \sum_{d | \# k} (\mu(d)\frac{N}d + O(1)) = N \prod_{p \le k} (1-p^{-1}) +O(2^{\pi(k)})$$

With $c_k(m)$ the $m$-th integer coprime to $\# k$ then $m = \sum_{n \le N, gcd(n,\# k) = 1} 1$ and $gcd(N,\# k) = 1$  implies  $c_k(m) = N$ so $$c_k(N \prod_{p \le k} (1-p^{-1}) +O(2^{\pi(k)})) = N+O(2^{\pi(k)}) , \qquad c_k(m) = \frac{m}{\prod_{p \le k} (1-p^{-1})}+O(2^{1+\pi(k)})$$

Whence $$\sum_{m \le \varphi(\# k)} \frac{c_k(m)}{m}=\sum_{m \le \varphi(\# k)}\frac{1}{\prod_{p \le k} (1-p^{-1})}+\frac{O(2^{1+\pi(k)})}{m} \\=\frac{\varphi(\# k)}{\varphi(\#k)/\#k}+O(2^{1+\pi(k)} \log \varphi(\# k))=  \# k+O(2^{1+\pi(k)} k) $$

where all the $O$ constants are $1$

Comment: This is a magisterial answer. Working through it was a really helpful exercise for me, thanks.